# Failing to reach checkbox within listbox item or bind data to it, or the checkbox to the textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

My item class has string name and bool picked. I use a class with a static ObservableCollection with static methods to maintain the list. This is all working.

I cannot access the checkbox within the listbox item. I've tried multiple ideas I've found on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I have tried so many things, it would be too long to mention them all.

This is the latest attempt.

It works when I leave the checkbox out of the code.

I understand I'm failing to access the checkbox, it's not being recognized as part of the list item.

But I just don't know how to fix it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
       DoubleTapped="ListBox1_DoubleTapped" SelectionMode="Multiple">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding Picked}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding();

    public MainPage()
    {
    //....stuff         
        ListBox1.DataContext = MyList.list;
        //... etc


    // This works!!
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update listbox after item has been added and
        // user has returned to main page.
        ListBox1.UpdateLayout();
    }

    // This works if I leave the checkbox out of it!!
    private void ListBox1_DoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)this.FindName("checkBox");
        // Find the index;
        int i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        // Some stuff..
        // This is what is bound to the checkbox in the xaml!!
        item.Picked = true;
        try
        {
        //Manually trying to change the checked of the checkbox!!
        // Yes increasingly desperate!!
            checkBox.IsChecked = true;

        }// Necessary as the checkbox is always throwing this.
        catch (NullReferenceException e) { }
    }

    // Alter Picked value to true  on checkbox selection.
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the index;
        //THE INDEX IS ALWAYS 1!!!
        int i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        try
        {
        //Trying again to manually manipulate, even though
        //the data is supposed to be bound.
            item.Picked = true;

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex){}
    }
```

I've tried to only include essential information.
I've left out margins, colors etc and basic declarations.. etc to try and reduce the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[access a named control inside a XAML DataTemplate](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html)

Comment: @user3956566 No problem. I was trying to do something similar, and that link is the only one that gave a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd provide an answer to elaborate on the accepted answer with the link that solved this for me.

Basically this link provides a good way to loop through the xaml hierarchy using a visual tree, to find controls within the ListBox. So my xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"  ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel ...>
                <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" ... />
                <TextBlock  ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

// To select list item and change Picked value to true.
private void ListBox1_DoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Find the index;
    int i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
    CheckBox checkBox = getCheckBox(ListBox1);
    try
    { 
        // Change Picked bool value.
        item.Picked = true;
        // Check CheckBox to show item selected.
        checkBox.IsChecked = true;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException exc) { }
}

// Taken and modified from Jerry Nixon. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html
// Find the checkBox for that ListBox item.
CheckBox getCheckBox(ListBox ListBox1)
{
    var _ListBoxItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem;
    var _Container = ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(_ListBoxItem);
    var _Children = AllChildren(_Container);
    var _Name = "checkBox";
    var _Control = (CheckBox)_Children.First(c => c.Name == _Name);
    return _Control;
}

// Taken and modified from Jerry Nixon. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html
// Get any child controls from ListItem Container.
// Using a visual tree to access elements on the page
// within the xaml heirarchy of nested elements/tags.
public List<Control> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
    {
    var _List = new List<Control> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (_Child is Control)
            _List.Add(_Child as Control);
        _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_Child));
    }

    return _List;
}
```

Basically this can be used for other events and controls. Useful code to have.